# Adminhtml - Trying to search in the product grid by custom column

Tags: adminhtml, magento-1.9.2.0, product-grid

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and i am rewriting the products grid table.

I have done a copy from the original `Grid.php` and created this:

`/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` and here is what it contains:

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('product_filter');

    }

    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
                $this->getCollection()->joinField('websites',
                    'catalog/product_website',
                    'website_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left');
            }
        }
        return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
        ));

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $this->addColumn('custom_name',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $store->getName()),
                    'index' => 'custom_name',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('type',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
                'width' => '60px',
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('set_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $sets,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sku',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'index' => 'sku',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('number',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Поръчка №'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer',
        ));

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn('price',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
        ));

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $this->addColumn('qty',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'type'  => 'number',
                    'index' => 'qty',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('visibility',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'visibility',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'status',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('websites',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'websites',
                    'type'      => 'options',
                    'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'     => array(
                            'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                            'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                        ),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
        ));

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Rss')) {
            $this->addRssList('rss/catalog/notifystock', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Notify Low Stock RSS'));
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('product');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
             'confirm' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray();

        array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Change status'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
             'additional' => array(
                    'visibility' => array(
                         'name' => 'status',
                         'type' => 'select',
                         'class' => 'required-entry',
                         'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
                         'values' => $statuses
                     )
             )
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/update_attributes')){
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('attributes', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Update Attributes'),
                'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product_action_attribute/edit', array('_current'=>true))
            ));
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction', array('block' => $this));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
            'store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'),
            'id'=>$row->getId())
        );
    }
}
```

The custom code i've added in the Grid.php is this:

```
    $this->addColumn('number',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Поръчка №'),
            'width' => '50px',
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer',
    ));
```

I have created and rendered also, i saw this in another answer:

```
<?PHP
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
      public function render(Varien_Object $row)
      {

        $productId = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
            $orders = array();
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId))
                ->load();
            foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
                $orders[$orderItem->getOrder()->getIncrementId()] = $orderItem->getOrder();
            }

            $first_key = key($orders);  
            return $first_key;


      }
}
```

I have added the additional column so i can display in every row in which order ID the product is purchased. I have no problems. Everything is correct, but the problem comes when i try to search with this custom column.

The order ID is displayed correctly in the column but can not be searched by order ID.

Where is my mistake, why it is not working and how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already posted that question yesterday. Please avoid such behavior as it is considered as spamming and use the edit feature to add more information to your original question.

Comment: yes but it is Still considered as spam. Edit your first question instead of deleting it and creating a new one

Comment: Can you tell me which attribute you want display in grid ?

Comment: I am searching by order id.

Comment: This is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284537/filtering-a-joined-column/15875005#15875005

Comment: What if a product is present in more than one order? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Product can't be in more than one order.

Answer (score 1):

Did you receive any errors when you tried to search?

If you got something like this:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'order_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: ...

You need to add the filter map to your collection. Please check use code:

```
$collection->addFilterToMap('entity_id', 'main_table.entity_id');
```

Or you can add the `filter_index` parameter to the attribute of the grid field

(e.g. `'filter_index'  => 'main_table.entity_id'`)

This is useful when you use joined tables in collection.

Comment: I do not receive any errors.

Comment: I do not know how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying order number by using custom renderer. Whenever you search any field using filters magento add that filter in where clause of collection query. And filter will be added on column specified in index or `filter_index` with `main_table`.
To know what exactly happening you can print your collections query by following line

```
echo (string) $collection->getSelect();
```

Add this line in  `_prepareCollection()` method just before return statement. You will see select query just before you products grid.

Now to implement your order number column i am suggesting you to use join query or subquery to display order number on products grid. And and `filter_index` line with `correlation_name.order_id` in `addColumn` function.
Hope this will help you to implement you solution in better way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i don't know how i can do that. Can you help me out?